# joining multiple dynamic lists of objects

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm really trying to build dynamic reports in C# based off of multiple stored procedures across multiple databases and then join the results.

Here is an example:

List 1:

```
  { monthyear = '032016', submitted = '56', approved = '27'},
  { monthyear = '042016', submitted = '67', approved = '30'}
```

List 2

```
  { monthyear = '032016', returned = '17'},
  { monthyear = '042016', returned = '22'}
```

Knowing that the "key" column is dynamic and the results built into each list are dynamic. I am however able to retrieve a string representation of the key column that joins the lists.

The result I am looking for is:

```
  { monthyear = '032016', submitted = '56', approved = '27', returned = '17'},
  { monthyear = '042016', submitted = '67', approved = '30', returned = '22'}
```

Both list are stored as an `IEnumerable<object>` with an intended result of       `IEnumerable<object>`.

Is there a way to join these, not concat, without looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in linq you can write the join query as this

```
var res = list1.Join(list2, a => a.monthyear , b => b.monthyear ,
(a, b) => new { a.monthyear,a.returned, b.submitted, b.approved});
```

but i`m not sure how it is implemented internally

**Edit**

in this case you`ll need to use reflection first (you can enhance this)

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(firstObj).GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo p2 in typeof(secondObject).GetProperties())
                if (p.Name == p2.Name)
                    match = p.Name;
        }
```

now the variable match stores the key as string

```
list1.Join(list2, a=>a.GetType().GetProperty(match).GetValue(a,null), b => b.GetType().GetProperty(match).GetValue(b,null), (a, b) => new { a.first, a.second..... });
```

or

```
, (a,b) => new { a, b});
```

my guide was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276566/how-can-you-loop-over-the-properties-of-a-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017282/access-property-in-lambda-expression-from-string-when-using-linq)

morever check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861059/select-all-columns-after-join-in-linq) to select all the properties if you don`t know their names

hope this helps

Comment: the issue is I don't know until I retrieve the results what the link column is, so I can't use the lambda syntax that needs to know about monthyear.

Comment: Where is match defined and what type of object is it?

Comment: Match is a string

Answer (score 0):

Well, looping is going to be required, if for no other reason than to loop through the SP results as they come in from the database.

That aside, you could have a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` that will hold the final result. Reflection can pull all properties out from each of the records as they come in, and drop them into a `Dictionary<string, object>` for each record (keyed by property name, value is property value). Then merge these dictionaries into the big `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` which is keyed by whatever property you're interested in (looks like the "monthyear" property).

Reflection might not even be necessary e.g. if you're using a `DataTable` then you already have programmatic access to all the record field names and values.