# Can I use String parameter as an entity property and an object property in Linq expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, linq-to-entities

This is my first question, I'm doing the best I can to be understand.

I want to insert in table that has many unique properties.

I want to use string instead of property in a Linq expression.

I want to make something like this:

```
public List<string> AddEmploye(Employe pEmploye)
{
   List<string> NonUnique = new List<string>();
   List<string> Prop = new List<string>
      {
         "ID",
         "NAS",
         "CODE",
      };

   foreach (var prop in Props)
   {
      var result = (from t in _context.TEMP02A
                  where t.prop == pEmploye.prop
                  select t.name).ToList();

      if (result.Count() > 0)
        NonUnique.Add(prop);
   }
   return NonUnique;
}
```

I tried many solutions proposed on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but neither worked for my case.

I tried these solutions:
[0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp),
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104050/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-object-getvalue),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017282/access-property-in-lambda-expression-from-string-when-using-linq),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770897/linq-access-property-by-variable),
and many others, but none of those solutions works for my case.

I expect the result.count to be `0` or higher, but when I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp), I got this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize propertyInfo.GetValue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Michael, where does Props come from? Also, I am not sure what your actual question is, could you try and explain it clearer what it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: It kind of looks like he is trying to access a column by string name using EF, but I am not sure.

Comment: Props are my entity properties that are unique column in my database table. I want to use strings instead of entity properties. The goal is to reduce the amount of code line since im reapeating the same process for 7 entity properties.

Comment: What is the type of `t` in the `_context.TEMP02A` table?  Is it also `Employee`?

Comment: Yes! Both type `t` and `pEmploye` are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [dynamic linq](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library). It's a bit old, but it allows you to do things like:

```
Where($"property_name_as_string = @0", some_value)
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
.Where(prop + " = @0",employee_prop_value_by_reflection_here)
.Select("Name");
```

As from your example:

```
var val = GetPropValue(pEmploye, prop);
_context.TEMP02A.Where(prop + " = @0",val);
```

Comment: I tried this : `var result = _context.TEMP02A.Where($"property_name_as_string == some_value");`   But i got this error : cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expression.Expression<System.Func<PropEntity.Employe, bool>>'

Comment: Starting from what you proposed, i went on this :  `var result = _context.TEMP02A.Where(t => GetPropValue(t,prop) == GetPropValue(pEmploye, prop)).Select(t => t.name);` .   This execute but when i add a `.ToList()`, i go on this error :   `System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetPropValue(System.Object, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'`

Comment: It looks like the  `GetValue()` method does not work in my expression :(

Comment: From you last exemple, it says : `No overload for method 'Where' takes 2 arguments`

Comment: Did you include the dynamic linq library? you need to include `using System.Linq.Dynamic`

Comment: Im probably missing something else because its said 'Dynamic' does not exist in th namespace 'System.Linq'. I have System.Linq and System.Linq.Expression

Comment: Install this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic