# Is it better DLinq over IQueryable or DLinq over IEnumerable for better performance?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

If I run against dlinq, for example

```
var custq = data.StoreDBHelper.DataContext.Customers as IEnumerable <Data.SO.Customer>;
```

I Thought it was not much of a difference against running:

```
var custq = data.StoreDBHelper.DataContext.Customers as IQueryable <Data.SO.Customer>;
```

As, IQueryable  inherits from IEnumerable.

But I discovered the following, if you call: 
   custq.Sum()
then the program will process this as you called .toList() it you use the 'as IEnumerable'
because the memory on the progam raised to the same level, when i tried, custq.ToList.Sum()
but not on the 'as IQueryable' (because the issue then running on sql server) and did not affect the memory usage of the program.

My question is simply this, should you not use 'as IEnumerable' on Dlinq? But 'as IQueryable' as an general rule? I know that if you are running standard iterations, it gets the same result, between 'as IEnumerable'and 'as IQueryable'.

But is it just the summary functions and delegate expressions in where statement that there will be a difference - or will you in general get better performance if you use 'as IQueryable'? (for standard iteration and filter functions on DLinq entities)

Thanks !

Comment: dlinq, IQueryable and IEnumerable are three different things.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you concerned about performance as in memory usage?

Comment: Technically Dynamic Linq is a library built on top of the `IQueryable `interface. `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` while technically connected normally mean quite different things. Dynamic Linq, through the `AsQueryable` can be used even on top of `IEnumerable` (see Gravell's [response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/486868/613130)), but I have't ever benchmarked the use of `AsQueryable` and personally think it (the `AsQueryable`) is a nearly useless hack in itself, good only as a theoretical experiment.

Comment: xanatos - Thanks for the information. I know this. I want to understand what happens under the hood, when using. filter .where and .select. etc. - and yes - Rikalous, i want the best performance on the client app, so the server do the work.

Comment: @Niklas No, your question show that you don't know this. The title is `IQueryable on Dlinq for best performance?` as if IQueryable was built on top of DLinq (while it's the opposite...) You should have asked: Is it better DLinq over IQueryable or DLinq over IEnumerable for better performance), while then in the question your two examples speak of `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` (and there isn't a third example using DLinq)

Comment: @xanatos - well, var custq - is an dlinq table result, and i use sum(). - yes you are right about the title - Is it better DLinq over IQueryable or DLinq over IEnumerable for better performance. Is better.

Comment: @Niklas Looking at the example: `data.StoreDBHelper.DataContext.Customers` seems to be one of the properties of the LINQ-to-SQL DBContext that return a IQueryable<T> of the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depends on what you want to do...
Casting it as IEnumerable will return an object you can enumerate... and nothing more.
So yes, if you call Count on an IEnumerable, then you enumerate the list (so you actually perform your Select query) and count each iteration.

On the other hand, if you keep an IQueryable, then you may enumerate it, but you could also perform database operations like Were, OrderBy or count. Then this will delay execution of the query and eventually modify it before running it.

Calling OrderBy on an enumerable browse all results and order them in memory. Calling OrderBy on a queryable simply adds ORDER BY at the end of your SQL and let database do the ordering.

In general, it is better to keep it as an IQueryable, yes... Unless you want to count them by actually browsing them (instead of doing a SELECT COUNT(*)...)

Comment: If i want to work with the IEnumerable, is it not better to use ToList() then, it seems to be quicker?

Comment: Doing a ToList will actually perform the SQL query once and sotre data in a list. So, it is faster cause you go only once to DB. Now, if your data has changed between 2 enumerations, not doing ToList will enable you to retrieve new data when doing second call (which may be something you don't care... it depends on your use case).

Comment: The scenario you described eagerness with new data, only seems to work if you have added the data in the same DataContext instance, even if you are running tolist () several times, it is my experience. Ie. the need to renew the DataContext instance to ensure that the new data will be included. With you might have a different experience?

Comment: Well, you are certainly right. I have not tested this as I have never had a need to refresh data between to enumerations. I didn't think about datacontext caching. But I think (and did not test) that if you completely disable caching, then you will have 2 round-up to DB and 2 different sets of data.